# What TypeScript type should React children be set to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Here's my layout:

```
export default function Layout(children:any) {
  return (
    <div className={`${styles.FixedBody} bg-gray-200`}>
      <main className={styles.FixedMain}>
        <LoginButton />
        { children }
      </main>

      <footer>
        <FooterNavigation />
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And my app:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

To make my code a little cleaner, I'd like to set `Layout(children:any)` to an actual type instead of any, but I get this warning on my app page on Component when I change it to `Layout(children:ReactNode)`:

> TS2322: Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes | (IntrinsicAttributes & string) |
> (IntrinsicAttributes & number) | (IntrinsicAttributes & false) |
> (IntrinsicAttributes & true) | (IntrinsicAttributes &
> ReactElement<...>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNodeArray) |
> (IntrinsicAttributes & ReactPortal)'.   Type '{ children: Element; }'
> has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

It makes sense then that I should set it to `Layout(children:IntrinsicAttributes) {` but when I do there's no option to import it. What should this be set to?

Comment: It should be set to `ReactNode`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### New answer for React version >= 18

The `FC` type in React 18 **does not** include the `children` property anymore. If you want to add `children` as a prop, you will have to do it manually:

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

interface MyProps {
   children?: ReactNode;
}

const MyComponent: FC<MyProps> = (props) => {
   return props.children;
}
```

---

---

---

> #### Old answer for React version < 18

The best way to properly type `children` is to use built-in type `FC`.

`import { FC } from 'react';`

If the only prop you expect is `children`:

```
const MyComponent: FC = (props) => {};
                       // props includes only children property
```

If you want to include more props than just `children`:

```
interface MyProps {
   name: string;
}

const MyComponent: FC<MyProps> = (props) => {};
                           // props includes children and name properties
```

Comment: This seems to have problems with the type `NextPage` when using it like so `const MyComponent: NextPage = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode })`

Comment: With `const Layout: FC = (props) => {}` using `{props.children}` returns an error saying that `children does not exist on type {}`.

Comment: @inzn Just tested it and it works well for me, even if `props.children` - no tsc errors are thrown

Comment: Okay, weird. Thanks though!!

Comment: @inzn You were probably using already React v18 that time. Please check updated answer :)

Answer (score 18):

The typings for React have a [`PropsWithChildren` type](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1349b640d4d07f40aa7c1c6931f18e3fbf667f3a/types/react/index.d.ts#L825) that you can use:

```
function Layout({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
    // ...
}
```

As others have stated, it's typed as:

```
children?: ReactNode;
```

Answer (score 4):

Define `LayoutProps`:

```
type LayoutProps = {children?: ReactNode}

export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
```

From: [GitHub comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35995#discussioncomment-2530620).

Answer (score 0):

just write

```
interface LayoutProps{
 children: React.ReactNode
}
```

and add this interface to your props

```
const layout = ({children}:LayoutProps) => {.....}
```